# Terraform not able to init with a user with attached Policy document with full access

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have my terraform backend as s3. I get the below error while init:

```
Error refreshing state: AccessDenied: Access Denied
    status code: 403, request id: EYE1JFR2028Y8WA, host id: TSfI4l7i0cSR+tBczEA5nbolYrbBNhieEYItTeN831SUcJ2EZtT91szja0u735Hk9EdWAc=
```

I am running terraform by exporting these three credentials of a user AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, AWS_DEFAULT_REGION. That user has a policy document attached which is:

```
    {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::test-tf-state"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I have cross checked bucket arn it is correct yet i get 403 AccessDenied error.
While I put "/*" as suffix in arn terraform init works successfully, example policy below:

```
        {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::test-tf-state/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I can't understand this behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your resource is:

```
"arn:aws:s3:::test-tf-state"
```

this refers only to **bucket**, not objects in the bucket. This only allows you to perform operations on a bucket, not the objects inside the bucket, nor upload objects to it. But TF must be able to upload and read objects from the bucket.

In contrast, when you have:

```
"arn:aws:s3:::test-tf-state/*"
```

then your permissions apply to **objects** in a bucket. This allows you to put, get or delete these objects.